# Handling abstract action in a JTextField

Tags: java, action, jtextfield

I have a JTextField that has an abstract action, which tests to see when I type in the enter key:

```
static Action action = new AbstractAction(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("done");
        textWindow.append(textInput.getText());
        inputEarly = textInput.getText();
        hasInput = true;
        textInput.setText("");
    }
};
```

And I have a while loop which is waiting to see if the enter key has been pressed, by waiting until the variable `hasInput = true`, however every time the enter key is pressed and the action works, I know this because I have it print out `"done"` in the console, it never breaks from the `while(true)` loop that I have got running below it:

```
while(true) {
        textWindow.append("localhost " + getDateTime() + " > ");
        while(true) {
            if(hasInput) {
                System.out.println("works");
                input = inputEarly;
                hasInput = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```

hasInput is declared:

```
public class Main_Menu extends JFrame{

    static Boolean hasInput = false;
```

Is there a reason why it won't work?

Comment: So you want to break the outer loop?

Comment: Two questions : 1. Why `while ( true )` inside `while ( true )`  ? 2. Could you show whre `hasInput` is declared ( `class`, `local` ?) One suggestion : No need to compare `hasInput == true`, just : `if ( hasInput )`

Comment: @Jorn Basically, I want the second loop to break, so that the rest of the things within the outer loop can run, and then It go back to the first loop again, and wait for another input by typing in enter.

Comment: @svasa There are two `while(true)` because the first one if keeping the program run continuously until you need it to end by typing "exit" and the second one is there so that the first `while(true)` loop will wait until there is actually an input to work with. Also i will change my evaulation and show where hasInput in declared

Comment: That boolean should probably be ```volatile```. But why this polling business? You could also call a method to process the input from your action.

Comment: @JornVernee Whats the difference between volatile and static? Edit - Just changed the boolean to volatile and it gives the error: Cannot make a static reference to a non-static field

Comment: ```volatile``` is there to indicate that the value might be changed from another thread, and the JVM should take that into account.

Comment: @JornVernee oh ok, i put both, and It's fine. how do you suggest i make a method to handle data input?

Comment: well, you've defined a method before right? I don't have any information to help you with that.

Comment: @JornVernee Oh nevermind, i have defined a method, but making the boolean volatile seemed to have made it work, thank you :)